# TextBlock tooltip problems with wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

I have a grid with a TextBlock. I am trying to display a tooltip over the TextBlock (specifically to display the full text if the text of the block is trimmed by CharacterEllipsis), but the tooltips do not appear when I hover the mouse over the textblock. Any ideas?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UnjoinedLampTemplate" DataType="{x:Type devices:DeviceViewModel}">
        <Grid Width="133.2"
              Margin="0,10,0,10"
              Cursor="Hand"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="DisplayColor" Grid.Row="0"
                    Width="70" Height="70"
                    CornerRadius="100"
                    Background="#54de61" />
            <Image Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="0"
                   Width="70" Height="70"
                   Source="path_to_component" />
            <Border x:Name="textDisplay" Grid.Row="0"
                    Visibility="Visible"
                    Background="Black" Opacity=".75"
                    BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White"
                    CornerRadius="5"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" Style="{StaticResource DeviceLabelStyle}">
                    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>
                                 <TextBlock Text="my tooltip" />
                        </ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>

            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Here is the DeviceLabelStyle referenced in the TextBlock:

```
   <Style x:Key="DeviceLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,3,5,3" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Does it work if you apply it to the `textDisplay` border instead?

Comment: It works for me without any problems.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Hm, it still did not work for me when it was applied to the text display border. Any ideas what might cause this not to work? I'm using tooltips elsewhere in this application without problems...

Comment: @TSM I thought it *might* be caused by the fact that the `TextBlock` doesn't have a background and it would require you to hover the pointer over a text stroke, that's why I asked if it works on the border. You may test the value of `IsHitTestVisible` with Snoop, but I have no further ideas